# Melhorar código jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz um código simples para um botão abrir um sidebar, mas acho esse código repetitivo, gostaria de saber como posso melhorar ele.

```
$('.openbtn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.sidebar').css('width', '250px');
    $('#lista-torneios').css('margin-left', '250px');
});
$('.closebtn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.sidebar').css('width', '0');
    $('#lista-torneios').css('margin-left', '0');
});
```

Comment: Se são dois botões, não vejo onde "reduzir o código repetido" que vá valer a pena seguindo esse objetivo...

Comment: A única forma que vejo de melhorar isso é associando com alguma classe CSS e fazendo um toggleClass(), mas ai nem precisaria de 2 botões como já comentado

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Já que os dois elementos usam o mesmo evento, pode agrupar os dois no mesmo seletor, e utilizar um ternário para alterar os valores, verificando com `$(this)` qual o elemento que disparou o evento e se ele tem a classe `.openbtn`: se tiver aplica o primeiro argumento do ternário, caso contrário o segundo.

```
$('.openbtn, .closebtn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // quem disparou o evento tem a classe .openbtn?
    var el = $(this).hasClass('openbtn');
    $('.sidebar').css('width', el ? '250px' : '0');
    $('#lista-torneios').css('margin-left', el ? '250px' : '0');
});
```

Veja que na variável `el` estou verificando se o botão que disparou o evento tem a classe `.openbtn`. Com isso o valor de `el` será um booleano `true` ou `false`, que será usado posteriormente no ternário (caso não saiba o que é uma operação ternária, [clique aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_tern%C3%A1ria)).

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('.openbtn, .closebtn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // quem disparou o evento tem a classe .openbtn?
    var el = $(this).hasClass('openbtn');
    $('.sidebar').css('width', el ? '250px' : '0');
    $('#lista-torneios').css('margin-left', el ? '250px' : '0');
});
```

```css
.sidebar{
   background: red;
   width: 0;
   transition: width .5s;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">div</div>
<button class="openbtn">Abre</button>
<button class="closebtn">Fecha</button>
```

Comment:  muito massa!

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Fica menos legível, porém da para fazer em uma linha:

```
$(document).on('click', e => $(e.target).hasClass('menu') ? $('.sidebar').toggle(500): null)
```

Veja o exemplo no [CodePen](https://codepen.io/angelorubin/pen/MRXXmE?editors=1011).